# Why is a "field" on a form called a field?

Tags: etymology, nouns

A simple question, so to re-iterate the title:

Why is a "field" on a form called a field?

A quick search for the etymology results in:

> Old English feld "plain, open land" (as opposed to woodland), also "a
>   parcel of land marked off and used for pasture or tillage," probably
>   related to Old English folde "earth, land," from Proto-Germanic
>   *felthuz "flat land" (common West Germanic, cf. Old Saxon and Old Frisian feld "field," Old Saxon folda "earth," Middle Dutch velt,
>   Dutch veld Old High German felt, German Feld "field," but not found
>   outside it; Swedish fält, Danish felt are borrowed from German), from
>   PIE *pel(e)-tu-, from root *pele- (2) "flat, to spread" (see plane
>   (n.1)).
>
> Finnish pelto "field" is believed to have been adapted from
>   Proto-Germanic. The English spelling with -ie- probably is the work of
>   Anglo-French scribes (cf. brief, piece). Collective use for "all
>   engaged in a sport" (or, in horseracing, all but the favorite) is
>   1742; play the field "avoid commitment" (1936) is from notion of
>   gamblers betting on other horses than the favorite. Field glasses
>   attested by 1836.

No mention of its use in forms?

Comment: It doesn't explain the etymology, but it's that way on forms because it's referring to the corresponding "field" in the database, meaning one particular value for one particular column. (Reference [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28computer_science%29).)

Comment: @starsplusplus fields on forms predate databases by *centuries*.

Comment: The origin is pretty straightforward. You have to call it *something*, and when you're looking at an empty rectangular space, you might as well go with *field*. Plain, open land on a sheet of paper. A rather transparent metaphor. *Then* one day computers come along and you just use for the GUI the same established nomenclature you've been using for paper.

Comment: Maybe I explained badly. I suppose the word "database" is generally thought of with regards to computers. I was trying to clarify that used in that way it refers to a particular segment of data (which could be in a filing cabinet or other manual bookkeeping of some kind). Perhaps the OP knew this, but it sounded to me like they were concentrating on the means of *gathering* said data.

Comment: Nope, I wanted to know the root of this. I.e. an application form where your write into the "field" using pen and ink. I'd presumed all other fields come from this earlier meaning.

Comment: @RegDwight: Fields on forms weren't called that until ***after*** the invention of punched cards; the earliest citation the OED has to either one is 1903, and that refers to punched cards—see Andrew's answer.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Is it so straightforward?  The `an empty rectangular space,` is probably best described as a box, so why not call that empty *parcel* shape a "box"  instead of "field"? Why not *land*, *strip*, *tab*, *container*....?

Comment: @Mari-LouA precisely right. If we do choose to call it a box, the reasoning for doing so is straightforward. If we do choose to call it a container, the reasoning for doing so is straightforward. And if we do choose to call it a field, the reasoning for doing so is straightforward. But we do have to choose to call it *something*. It's impractical to call it fifty different names at once. We have to pick one good name. And so one good name we've picked. (As an aside, a *box* is three-dimentional. The thing we're looking to name here only has two dimensions. So *field* actually is better.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My [Glossary of Computing Terms: An Introduction](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Glossary-Computing-Terms-Introduction/dp/0521317770/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1390475589&sr=1-1&keywords=0521317770) (pub BCS, 1984) says

> **Field** is a predetermined section of a record

which covers forms as well.

OED shows the origin is surprisingly early:

> **19.** *Computing.* Any one of a number of places where a user is expected to enter a single item of a particular type of data; an item of such data; *esp.* one in a database record. Cf. *data field n.* at **data** *n.*
>
> Originally a group of columns on a punched card.
>
> > 1903   *Jrnl. Polit. Econ.* 11 372   The fields are to be punched in the regular order by touching the keys indicated from left to right.

*Data field* was apparently first mentioned in a patent:

> **data field**  *n.* a section of a record, esp. in a database, in which an item of data is entered; each of the particular types of data held in a database.
>
> > 1929   *Brit. Patent 302,314* 9/9   A previous inventory perforated strip P1, the separate data fields of which give, inter alia, the following data [etc.].

It's a fairly small step to extend other earlier uses to reach the above meanings:

> **10. a.** An enclosed or marked-out area [for playing sport]

or even

> **II.** An area of operation or observation.
> **12. a.** An area or sphere of action, enquiry, or interest; a (wider or narrower) range of opportunities, or of objects, for activity or consideration; a theme, a subject. Freq. with *of.*
> **b.** As a mass noun: scope, opportunity; extent of material for some specified action or operation. Freq. with *for.*
> **c.** A particular branch of study or area of expertise or competence; a subject. Also more fully **field of study.**

Comment: I'd presumed that the computing term comes from the earlier "field on a paper form"? i.e. I'm filling in a written application form using pen and ink and I write the data into the field(s). So it was this I was after really.

Comment: @Liam: I suspect the term for a paper form comes from the computing term. Certainly, the OED doesn't have any citations for "field" on a paper forms that are earlier than the punched card citation.

Comment: that never even occurred to me. I'd presumed that paper forms pre-date computing forms so it must come from the earlier version. So what did they call fields on paper forms before computers??!

Comment: Very good question. When I was in grade school, we said "fill in the blanks". But "blank" was an informal, childish word, and the correct, grown-up word was "field".

Comment: @Liam Isn't that more or less what the 1903 quotation is telling us? The columns on the punch card were, one would expect, empty spaces for entering information (albeit not actual text).

Comment: From the OED: **blank**, definition 5a. A blank space in a written or printed document. Earliest citation *1570*. Earliest comprehensible citation:
*1632  Warrantes..with blankes for names of plaintiff and defendant.*

Answer (score 1):

Not a big mental stretch to got from a "field of study" to a "field of data"

Comment: This appears to be a comment to Andrew's answer, accidentally posted as an answer?